# NDK passing byte array to java, getting [B@... instead of contents

Tags: android, reflection, java-native-interface, sms, private-members

I am trying to extract the contents of a byte array from an Android SmsTracker and convert to the txt body but when I print the contents I get [B@ADDRESS instead, here's my code

```
static void my_gsmsendsms(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jobject tracker)
{
    char bodychars[25] = "unable to pass body ";
    jstring smsBody = (*env) ->NewStringUTF(env,bodychars);
    jclass trackercls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,tracker);
    jfieldID mDfieldId = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, trackercls, "mData", "Ljava/util/HashMap;");
    jobject mData = (*env)->GetObjectField(env,tracker,mDfieldId);
    jclass bodunpack = (*env)->FindClass(env, "net/example/smsDispatcher/BodyUnpacker");
    jmethodID unpackbod = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, bodunpack, "UnpackBody", "(Ljava/util/HashMap;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (unpackbod) {
        jstring body = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, bodunpack, unpackbod, mData);
        const char *natBody = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, body, 0);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "ApOw", "body is defined %s",natBody);
        smsBody =body;
    }

    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,tracker);
    jfieldID fieldId = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "mDestAddress", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring destAddress = (*env)->GetObjectField(env,tracker,fieldId);
    const char *natBodyString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, smsBody, 0);
    char msgbody[140] = " smsbody: ";
    strcat(msgbody, natBodyString);
    const char *natDstString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, destAddress, 0);
    char msg[30] = "smstarget: ";
    strcat(msg, natDstString);
    char charres[170];
    strcpy(charres, msg);
    strcat(charres, msgbody);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, destAddress, natDstString);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, smsBody, natBodyString);
    log("%s ",charres)
}
```

The output I get is : `smstarget: 0123456789 smsbody: [B@b23f41d8`

And I have a Java class that takes the byte array out of the HashMap and converts it to a string using the correct class in SMSDispatcher.

```
public class BodyUnpacker 
{   
    public static String UnpackBody(HashMap<String, Object> mData)
    {
        System.out.println("net.example.smsDispatcher.BodyUnpacker");
        byte[] pdu = (byte []) mData.get("pdu");

        SmsMessage s1 = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
        String rs = "cannot read body";
        if (s1 != null) {
            System.out.println("BodyUnpacker: outgoing SMS");
            try {
                if (s1.getDisplayMessageBody() != null) {
                    System.out.println("BodyUnpacker: " + s1.getDisplayMessageBody());
                    rs = s1.getDisplayMessageBody();
                }
                else if (pdu != null) rs = String.valueOf(pdu);
                else rs="message body unavailable";
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                rs="message body unavailable";
            }
        }
        return rs;
    }
```

So have I missed something obvious or why is my return string actually the address of the array I want to return?
I've tried to track this down from SmsManager but it goes through Isms.aidl and I lose where that comes out. however GsmSMSDispatcher does handle the call:

```
    protected void sendSms(SmsTracker tracker) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = tracker.mData;

            byte smsc[] = (byte[]) map.get("smsc");
            byte pdu[] = (byte[]) map.get("pdu");
```

which is basically what I'm trying to do, but am forced to use Native because the SmsTracker is a protected innerclass.
I'd be immensely grateful to anyone who could shed a light on what the native end is doing with my pointer to the hashmap that is causing the cast to go wonky.
My code is in fact triggering off the gsm version of SendSms, so I am pretty certain of the classes here.

Comment: Instead of using JNI, you coild employ reflections. It's pure Java, and not less powerful.

Comment: It's not clear where you print `[B@ADDRESS`, please mark the place in your code.

Comment: it in the section marked Do stuff with string, Ill edit.

Comment: Does `__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "ApOw", "body is defined %s",natBody)` print the correct string?

Comment: I have 2 ways of sending the message, when I send it via the SmsManager.sendtext call I get "body is defined [B@b248d120 "

If I send it with the Android messanger app I get "body is defined message body unavailable"
 in the log. This means I am getting a null pointer exception, must not be a text or an email.

Comment: It seems, `net/example/smsDispatcher/BodyUnpacker` does not work well.